# Camunda Parallel Gateway with compensating actions throws exceptions when an error occurs

Tags: camunda

I'm trying to create a simple Camunda BPM workflow with a parallel gateway and compensating actions like this: [image: My workflow]

All the Service Tasks are configured as external tasks that are executed by a C# program.  This program calls the `fetchAndLock` method on the API to get a list of tasks to execute and then executes these tasks in parallel in the background.  I'm experiencing some problems with this approach:

The **Lock** in the `fetchAndLock` method doesn't seem to do anything and the workflow engine does not seem to wait until all the fetched tasks are handled whenever one of the tasks is completed with a `bpmnError'.  Instead it immediately plans the execution of the compensating actions for the tasks it already received a` complete` call and deletes the instances of all the other planned tasks without waiting for their results.

This results in the following problems:

- The C# program continues to execute the unfinished tasks and when they complete it tries to call the `complete` method on the API, but that fails with a 404 error because the Camunda engine already deleted these task instances.
- The compensating actions for these tasks are never called, which leaves the business process in an invalid state.

What am I doing wrong?  I am not very familiar with BPMN so maybe there is a better way to design this process.  Or is this a **major bug** in Camunda?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that after the parallel gateway there are two errors that trigger the event subprocess twice. You can try using the [terminate event](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/reference/bpmn20/events/terminate-event/) in the event subprocess

Comment: Thanks but no, there is only 1 error in 1 of the parallel tasks.  I would expect that when calling fetchAndLock in the engine, all 3 tasks get locked and the engine would wait for all of them to finish before planning the compensation logic for all 3 tasks, if 1 or more of them failed.  
Instead when the program reports the failure of a task to the engine and asks for more work, it gets the compensation for the task that failed.  When that is complete, the notification is sent and the workflow stops.  Resulting in 404s when the program tries to report the success of the other tasks.